# Kohana 3.3 not using MySQLi driver

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, kohana-3.3

I'm working on a project that uses Kohana 3.3.
I've run into a problem where I want to connect to a database. The application is telling me it's using MySQL and it's decrepated.

To solve this I've downloaded a MySQLi driver for Kohana 3.3 and followed the instructions (creating a mysqli folder in the modules folder and adding a new line in bootstrap.php to enable it).

However when I try to perform any database actions it still says it's using MySQL.
The error reads: "Database_Exception [ 8192 ]: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead".

The line I'm using to enable the module is `'mysqli'  => MODPATH.'mysqli',  // MySQLi support for Kohana`

The MySQLi driver I'm using is [this](https://github.com/Azuka/Kohana-Database-MySQLi) (links to github).

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using modules `mysqli` and `database` at the same time? I think this should not be declared as a module but rather as a driver in your DB module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enabling the module isn't enough.

[Since Kohana 3.3 the autoloader is case sensitive](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions), so `MODPATH/mysqli/classes/kohana/database/mysqli.php` should become `MODPATH/mysqli/classes/Kohana/Database/MySQLi.php` for example.

You have to edit your APPPATH/config/database.php and set the driver to 'MySQLi' or set Database::$default to the correct default database instance name. (The one using 'MySQLi' as the driver.)

And just to be sure, do NOT edit config files outside of APPPATH. Instead, copy the file to APPPATH and edit that file. You generally should not have to edit files outside of APPPATH. Updating modules to work with a new version is allowed of course. But config files outside of APPPATH should serve as examples/blueprints.

Answer (score 6):

I've bumped into this issue as well.

The problem has been discussed on the Kohana forums.  The next version (3.4) will include changes to the Kohana Database module so you can use the MySQLi library.

Until then I've disabled deprecated errors appearing by changing the error_reporting in `index.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Hope this helps